# dropdown list item selection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, html-select

I am using the below code to bind a dictionary object into a dropdown list and select value from the dropdown list.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(1, "apple");
        dict.Add(2, "bat");
        dict.Add(3, "cat");
        ddl.DataSource = dict;
        ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
        ddl.DataTextField = "Value";  //will display in ddl
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string key = ddl.SelectedValue;
        string value = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

Whatever value I selected in ddl its always getting '1' in key and "apple" in value. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your binding the list on each post back, you should check `IsPostBack` like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack) // better if you refactor binding code to a method
       {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(1, "apple");
        dict.Add(2, "bat");
        dict.Add(3, "cat");
        ddl.DataSource = dict;
        ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
        ddl.DataTextField = "Value";  //will display in ddl
        ddl.DataBind();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `dropdownlist` get reset every time page gets loaded, so update your code with [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
    // Validate initially to force asterisks
    // to appear before the first roundtrip.

    Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    dict.Add(1, "apple");
    dict.Add(2, "bat");
    dict.Add(3, "cat");
    ddl.DataSource = dict;
    ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
    ddl.DataTextField = "Value";  //will display in ddl
    ddl.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sudha, you can use choose the Map interface.

That will actually fulfil your requirement since that stores data in the combination of key and value pairs.

Comment: Rajesh, Map is in Java, Dictionary is equivalent in C#